# Basketball player scored points calculator not working

Tags: c++11

I'm making a program, where you input n amount of players, threes attempted, threes made, two-pointers attempted, two-pointers made, free throws attempted, free throws made, then I check that there aren't more made shots than attempts, and the program has to find the most accurate player's total score (most accurate is the one who has most attempts made from all shots combined).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Player {
private:
    long int thra, thrm, twa, twm, fta, ftm;
public:
    void Input() {
        long int thra1, thrm1, twa1, twm1, fta1, ftm1;
        cin >> thra1 >> thrm1 >> twa1 >> twm1 >> fta1 >> ftm1;
        if (thrm1 <= thra1 && twm1 <= twa1 && ftm1 <= fta1) {
            thra = thra1;
            thrm = thrm1;
            twa = twa1;
            twm = twm1;
            fta = fta1;
            ftm = ftm1;
        }
        else {
            returnFalse();
        }
    }

    bool returnFalse() {
        return false;
    }

    long int mostPoints() {
        double acc = 0, maxacc = 0;
        long int maxpts = 0;

        if ((thra + twa + fta) > 0) {
            acc = 100 * ((thrm + twm + ftm) / (thra + twa + fta));
        }
        else {
            acc = 0;
        }
        if (acc > maxacc) {
            maxacc = acc;
            maxpts = (thrm) * 3 + (twm) * 2 + ftm;
        }
        return maxpts;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<Player*> players;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Player *newPlayer = new Player();
        newPlayer->Input();
        players.push_back(newPlayer);
    }
    long int points = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        points = players[i]->mostPoints();
    }

    cout << points;
}
```

With any input the answer is 0 and I can't spot my mistake. Could someone please help?

Comment: I see integer division. Guessing the issue is there.

Comment: Also in `Input()`, `returnFalse()` is pointless.

Comment: i made sure I don't divide by zero with an if that checks if all of the shot attempts are more than 0

Comment: Let’s say you made 3 out of 5 shots. `3 / 5 = 0` with integers. You need to promote to `float` or `double`.

Comment: changing from int to double helped, atleast im getting somewhat of a result now, I'm going to check for other mistakes because it still outputs a wrong result

Comment: `if (acc > maxacc) {...` Move that to `main()`. For each player compare the result of ‘mostPoints()` to `maxacc`

Comment: Side note: there’s no need to use pointers in your vector. Just use `vector<Player> players;`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to get it working properly